# How can I find out where the gvm installed groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a mac running OSX 10.9.2. and I just installed the gvm and used that to install Groovy. I want to get a test project set up to use for my ide, but I don't know where to tell my ide to find the Groovy SDK.

Typeing "help" into the Groovy shell doesn't reveal anything helpful either. How can I find out where Groovy is installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you installed the latest, it's in `~/.gvm/groovy/2.2.2`

The symbolic link `~/.gvm/groovy/current` will point to the current version you're using

Comment: The doc for Groovy also helps here: http://gvmtool.net/ "It will then create a .gvm/ folder in your home directory, and neatly install all candidates beneath it."

Comment: I read that on the GVM home page. I guess the question that I should ask then is how can I point my IDE to this folder? The folder is hidden so I can't select it when it asks me for a location.

Comment: You can't type the location in by hand? Does pressing `/` bring up a location entry box?

Comment: @tim_yates I figured it out. I had to create a java module and then add groovy and I was able to type in the location there. I had been trying to add a groovy module from the start and there wasn't anyplace for me to type things.