# What directory/location does posh-gvm install libraries/programs/packages in Windows

Tags: windows, gvm, posh-gvm

I would like to know where `posh-gvm` (SDKMAN for windows) installs its software.

I've had a brief look in Program Files, %APPDATA% and %HOMEDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME% but couldn't find anything. The information is surprisingly hard to find online.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262496/how-can-i-find-out-where-the-gvm-installed-groovy) about Unix `gvm`'s dir install-dir at ~/.gvm, I have found the directory located under

```
%HOMEDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%\.posh-gvm
|__ groovy
|__ scala
|__ grails
\__ etc...
```